# Solving a non-linear diffusion equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, nonlinear-system, heat-equation

I'm currently trying to solve the equation $$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{D}{C}\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}\right),
$$ where D is a constant and $C \equiv C(x,t).$ The initial condition on $C$ is $C(x,0)=N_0 \delta(x)$, but further reasonable boundary conditions may be assumed true. So far I've tried solving either it using its Fourier transform or by treating it similarly to the heat equation (http://www.math.toronto.edu/courses/apm346h1/20129/L9.html), but my attempts have been unsucsessful. Any idea on how to find a solution? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Separation of variables might be useful. Set e.g. C=f(t)*g(x) and solve both resulting ODEs.

Comment: Please give some background on why this equation is of interest. Also try scaling transformations as in your heat equation notes.